# Learning about lvalue and rvalue and not sure why this code works

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm was playing around with C++(It's been over 10 years since I used the language) and wrote the the small program below and was a bit surprised by the result:

```
#include <iostream>

int& getReference()
{
    int x = 33;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = getReference() = 4;
    auto b = getReference();

    std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is "a: 4 c: 33" when I was expecting "a: 33 c: 33".

The reason I was expecting "a" to equal 33 is because i'm first setting the getReference lvalue return reference to 4 and than "return x" is overriding that lvalue reference with 33.

Anyway, I thought maybe can explain where I'm wrong here?

Thanks for everyone's help!

**Edit 1**
So many responses really quick.  Thanks everyone for your help!

**Edit 2** I'm not sure if it's too late to add this or I should make it a new question. I changed "x" as a global variable and got the same answer.  So i'm now still confused because the global variable x didn't go away.

Comment: You're returning a reference to local variable that goes out of scope. Using it is undefined behaviour. And it's vice versa - the returned reference is assigned with 4.

Comment: In addition, `auto` never deduces a reference type, so your declarations are both making *copies*.

Comment: Did you disable compiler warnings? I wonder if there are still compilers, that do not warn about this kind of problem.

Comment: jrok: So getReference() = 4 is really setting local variable x, which is replacing 33?

Comment: Sort of. The local doesn't exists anymore when assignment happens. The program is illegal so it's a bit futile to reason about it.

Comment: jrok: I understand.  Pretty much, i'm just getting what was last left at that address space, which happens to be 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function should not return a reference to a local variable. The problem is that you're returning a reference to `x`, but `x` goes out of scope at the end of the function. As soon as it goes out of scope, any references to it are invalid and dereferencing them invokes undefined behavior.

If that were fixed, and you returned a reference to a globally-scoped variable instead, you would still see the same behavior, because:

```
auto a = getReference() = 4;
```

The right-hand expression is evaluated first:

```
getReference() = 4
```

This assigns 4 to the reference returned by the function. Then, the result of that expression (`4`) is assigned to `a`.

```
auto b = getReference();
```

Here, `getReference()` is evaluated. As you pointed out, the function resets the value of the variable it returns a reference to. So the result of the expression is `33` which gets assigned to `b`.

Comment: OK this explains it a bit.  However, I would think getReference assignment to 33 in the function happens after so it would be 33 and not 4.

Comment: @Michael No it doesn't; `getReference()` is evaluated first, *then* 4 is assigned to the lvalue it returns.

Comment: Ok, for some reason I'm thinking it happens right to left not left to right.

Comment: @Michael It has to happen left-to-right because you can't perform an assignment until you have an lvalue (the left-hand side of the `=`) to assign it to. Note, though, that `=` is still *right-associative*. So in `a() = b() = c`, first `b()` is evaluated; `c` is then assigned to it; then `a()` is evaluated and the result of `b() = c` (which is `c`) is assigned to the lvalue result of `a()`. Confused yet? ;-)

Comment: I think I understand. So first it runs function getReference (which gives you the lvalue) and the results of x after getReference runs is 33.  Now it runs right to left. So really "auto a = getReference() = 4;" is the same as "auto a = x = 4;", where x = 33?

Comment: @Michael Almost, except that in your code `x` is a reference to a variable that no longer exists (it went out of scope); it's therefore invalid and assigning to it is undefined behavior. Otherwise yes, you have it exactly.

Comment: I understand that. However if x is global, it would be true?

Answer (score 5):

Your `getReference` returns a reference to a local variable, so by the time the function returns, it's a dangling reference (i.e., the variable to which it referred has been destroyed). Any use of that reference (reading or writing) causes undefined behavior.

So, basically, you've broken the contract with the compiler in a way that allows it to do anything. You have no right to be surprised at any result.

If you change it to a global:

```
#include <iostream>

int x;

int& getReference()
{
    x = 33;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = getReference() = 4;
    auto b = getReference();

    std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Then you should expect `a: 4 b: 33`. The first invocation retrieves a reference to `x`, then assigns `4` to the referent, than retrieves `4` from the referent and assigns it to `a`. The second invocation assigns 33 to the referent, then retrieves the 33 from the referent and assigns it to `b`.

If you changed `a` and `b` to references:

```
    // ...
auto &a = getReference() = 4;
auto &b = getReference();
    // remainder unchanged
```

Then you should see `a:33 b:33`. In this case, both `a` and `b` refer to the original variable. Since `getReference` assigns `33` *after* the `4` gets assigned, the value `4` is overwritten with `33`.

In other words, in this case both `a` and `b` are just references to the single global, so the overall effect is pretty much the same as if you had:

```
int x;

int main(){ 
   x = 33;
   x = 4;
   x = 33;
   std::cout << x << " " << x << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That code is undefined behavior, you are returning a reference to a local object. Any use of the reference will be undefined behavior. Now, assuming that the reference returned was to an object with a longer life span...

```
auto a = getReference() = 4;
```

The order of operations is equivalent to the parenthesized expresssion:

```
auto a = (getReference() = 4);
```

That is, you get a reference to an object (hopefully alive!) update that object to hold the value 4, then assign the result of that to the newly created `a`.